# How to get data from Custom Dialog Window in Google App Script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I created a [Custom Dialog Window](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) in Google Spreadsheet using Google App Script that looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the data from the window to my spreadsheet.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

<form action="google.script.run.testing143()">
  Task Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="taskNumber" value="">
  <br><br>
   Task Date:<br>
  <input type="text" name="taskDate" value="">
  <br><br>
   Customer Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="customerName" value="">
  <br><br>
   Customer Site:<br>
  <input type="text" name="customerSite" value="">
  <br><br>
  <select>
  <option value="status">Status</option>
  <option value="complete">Complete</option>
  <option value="scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option value="reschedule">Reschedule</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
   Status Date:<br>
  <input type="text" name="statusDAte" value="">
  <br><br>
   Location:<br>
  <input type="text" name="location" value="">
  <br><br>
   Description:<br>
  <input type="text" name="description" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

  <script>
  function testing143(){
  Logger.log('With Success')  ///Doesn't work
  var lmnt = document.getElementByName('usrname'); //Wrong

  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click 'submit' it takes me to an error 400 page.
I can create a function that takes the data as a parameter like:

```
function getNewTask(number,date,status...)
```

Can I use `document.getElement` ? If so how is that done?

Your help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: You need to use google.script.run to pass data from your html dialog to the spreadsheet and you can return values from that script using withSuccessHandler or withFailureHandler see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've taken your code and modified to work.

In Code.gs

```
function testing143(obj) {
  Logger.log(obj);
  return "hello";
}
```

In HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

<form id="myForm">
  Task Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="taskNumber" value="">
  <br><br>
   Task Date:<br>
  <input type="text" name="taskDate" value="">
  <br><br>
   Customer Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="customerName" value="">
  <br><br>
   Customer Site:<br>
  <input type="text" name="customerSite" value="">
  <br><br>
  <select name="status">
  <option value="status">Status</option>
  <option value="complete">Complete</option>
  <option value="scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option value="reschedule">Reschedule</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
   Status Date:<br>
  <input type="text" name="statusDate" value="">
  <br><br>
   Location:<br>
  <input type="text" name="location" value="">
  <br><br>
   Description:<br>
  <input type="text" name="description" value="">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="testing143()">
</form> 

  <script>
  function success(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }

  function testing143(){
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm").elements;
    var obj ={};
    for(var i = 0 ; i < form.length ; i++){
        var item = form.item(i);
        obj[item.name] = item.value;
    }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success).testing143(obj);
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you!